# Image gallery. How to advance to next image?

Tags: flex4, flash-builder

Ive trying to make a image gallery using xml feed and the sparks list component. that displays images in a horizontal list. which of-course each item can be clicked to see the larger image, but then to view the to other images or the next image in the list you have to hit the back button and then select another.

How can i move image for move to the next item int he list without having to go back to main list.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code? Where exactly do you have a problem?

Comment: here is my first post..
http://forums.adobe.com/message/5202163#5202163

Comment: could you provide your xml-file or the feed to let me check the code? You can send me it to my email if you want (anton.i.belov (at) gmail.com). It will help me to give you an answer.

Comment: the xml feed im using is just a simple one. here is a idea

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<bookpage>
<id>1</id>
<thumbimage>coverth.jpg</thumbimage>
<largeimage>cover.jpg</largeimage>
</bookpage>
<bookpage>
<id>2</id>
<thumbimage>insidecoverth.jpg</thumbimage>
<largeimage>insidecover.jpg</largeimage>
</bookpage>
</items>

Comment: should it be done as a mobile application? In the task there is no word about the mobile case, but I think it is so, isn't it?